# How can I send a variable and a photo to display on Apple Watch

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch

I would like to send a rgb variable, and be able to send a thumbnail gallery to the Apple Watch. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're targeting watchOS 2, you'll want to use WatchConnectivity for that. Create and start a `WCSession` on both ends, then use `transferUserInfo:` or other methods to send data from the phone to the watch.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to use [WCSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSession_class/index.html)'s [transferFile:metadata:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WCSession/transferFile:metadata:) to do this, where you store the thumbnail gallery as a single file (zip, perhaps?). If you'd want the thumbnails to show up as soon as possible, you could also consider sending them individually.